# Codeigniter: load Views progressively

Tags: php, performance, codeigniter

I moved my scraping/parsing PHP code to Codeigniter recently. It uses *cURL* and *SimpleHtmlDom* class to retrieve data from the target URL which is later processed by the model functions several other libraries.

There are **several requests to external Webs and APIs** so the original PHP script took **up to 20 seconds** to load the complete page, but **it was OK** because the PHP was split into several blocks and while the processes lower down were running the page was already rendering HTML, which could be read by the user while the rest of the data was being processed and displayed.

The problem with switching to Codeigniter is that **no HTML is rendered until the Controller script has been executed completely**, even if the data processes are split into blocks and loaded by separate Views.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class HomePage extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('simple_html_dom');
    $this->load->library('library1');
    $this->load->library('library2');
    $this->load->library('library3');

    $this->load->model('HomePage_model');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');

    $targeturl = 'http://www.example.com';

      $variable1 = library1::method1($targeturl);
      $variable2 = $this->HomePage_model->method2($targeturl);
      $data1 = array('variable1' => $variable1, 'variable2' => $variable2);

    $this->load->view('first_set_of_data', $data1);

      $variable3 = library2::method2($targeturl);
      $variable4 = $this->HomePage_model->method3($targeturl);
      $data2 = array('variable3' => $variable3, 'variable4' => $variable4);

    $this->load->view('second_set_of_data', $data2);

      $curlinfo = $this->HomePage_model->cURLmethod($targeturl);
      $data3 = array('curlinfo' => $curlinfo);

    $this->load->view('third_set_of_data', $data3);

    $this->load->view('sidebar');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}

/* End of file homepage.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/homepage.php */
```

I'm not trying to optimize my code so it runs faster, it's already been revised several times... what I'm trying to do is to **load Views progressively** as the data corresponding to each View is ready, while the data for the other Views is being processed.

Comment: the best way to do it, in codeigniter or in any framework is to use the **ajax** methodology to load the extra data after page loading.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmad for your help. I'm new to Ajax, could you develop on how it could be implemented or link to an article where I could start learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a problem with an unelegant solution. I'd imagine you to be forced to chop all the views so that no view is called within another, and load each relevant view per request.

So instead of `views/index.php` having:

```
<html>
<body>
<? $this->load->view('content') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

You'd have `view/index_start.php`:

```
<html>
<body>
```

and `view/index_end.php`:

```
</body>
</html>
```

Between them, load seperate views after each request. Load all views from the controller. Again, this design is *not* recommended.

```
echo $this->load->view('file', array(), TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Robin. However, that's what I've already tried... the controller currently loads view('templates/header') and view('templates/footer') with several views in the middle, and still won't display them progressively.

Comment: Are you sure you're loading them at the right moment? What happends if you put a heavy call between 2 views? Also try to run a `echo $this->load->view('file', array(), TRUE)` instead. It might solve it.

Comment: Thanks! The echo `$this->load->view('file', array(), TRUE)` solved the problem. Anyway, I'll try to implement an ajax solution like @Ahmad suggested.

Comment: Yeah, do consider that approach. It's a more logical solution, since most browsers prefer to have the entire website at once, then load many different heavy stuff afterwards.